# How do I get the location of a file in a WiX Script

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

How do I make a custom action that references a file on the command line?

I have the custom action accessing the MYSQL properties correctly, but I haven't figured out the incantation to access the path to the installed sql script.

Below are the relevant sections of the WiX script.  I am trying to get the custom action to reference the path to MYSQL_SCRIPTS file.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
   <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="MyProgram">
     <Directory Id="DbSetupDir" Name="DbSetup">
        <Component Id="SqlScripts" Guid="MYGUID">
           <File Id="MYSQL_EXE" Source="mysql.exe" Vital="yes" />
           <File Id="MYSQL_SCRIPTS" Source="MYSQL_SCRIPTS.sql" Vital="yes" />
        </Component>
     </Directory>
   </Directory>
 </Directory>

 ...

<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' 
  FileKey='MYSQL_EXE'
  ExeCommand='--host=[MYSQL_SERVER]
  -u [MYSQL_USERNAME]
  -P [MYSQL_PORT]
  --password=[MYSQL_PASSWORD]
  -e [DbSetupDir]\ALS_Scripts.sql' 
  Return='check'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [#MYSQL_SCRIPTS] [conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609(VS.85).aspx), this will translate to the  full path of those files at setup time.

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' 
  FileKey='MYSQL_EXE'
  ExeCommand='--host=[MYSQL_SERVER]
  -u [MYSQL_USERNAME]
  -P [MYSQL_PORT]
  --password=[MYSQL_PASSWORD]
  -e [#MYSQL_SCRIPTS]' 
  Return='check'/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The solution worked and the link was exactly what I was looking for.